# Difference between EnterWriteLock and TryEnterWriteLock(Timeout.Infinite)

Tags: c#, locking, readerwriterlockslim

i'm a bit confused on the differences between `EnterWriteLock()` and `TryEnterWriteLock()` with `Timeout.Infinite` as parameter of ReaderWriterLockSlim.
What is the point of giving an infinite timeout for entering the lock instead of using directly EnterWriteLock?
What i have understood those two methods are exectly the same? What I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[They're identical](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/system/threading/ReaderWriterLockSlim/ReaderWriterLockSlim.cs,449):

```
public void EnterWriteLock()
{
    TryEnterWriteLock(-1);
}
```

It's a bit easier to read the intent of `lock.EnterWriteLock()`, compared to `lock.TryEnterWriteLock(-1)` / `lock.TryEnterWriteLock(Timeout.Infinite)`.